# HTTP GET: Way out for writing a GET call greater than the allowed size?

Tags: http, get

I want to send a list of Ids to the server and get the details from the server.

For Example:
https://example.com/index.html?ids="list_of_ids"

However, the ids list can sometimes be too long and exceed the permissible URL limit.

Is there any solution to this problem or maybe a work around. Although, I don't want to use a POST call for the same. Can anything be done to the GET call to make it work?

Comment: What language are you using? Are you just simply putting that query string in the browser?

Comment: You can attach JSON data to the body of the request.

Comment: Most browsers impose the limitation of length in the URL. Certain clients such as `curl` don't impose this limitation.

Comment: @LeoCorrea anyway too long URLs should be avoided in good programming

Comment: Do your IDs satisfy any criteria? Can you add an example containing some possible values for IDs? I think to pass the IDs in a different way somehow (E.g.: if you have 50 identical IDs, you can use `50xYourID` or if you have IDs like `1000000` you can send `1M`), otherwise you need to use another HTTP method.

Comment: _Why_ don’t you want to use POST?

Comment: I guess you can use request-body in GET call as well. Please refer to the link below where Elastic search uses the request-body in a GET call. But HTTP libraries of certain languages (notably JavaScript) don’t allow GET requests to have a request body. 
"https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html"